# Celery Redis returns "Received unregistered task of type"

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

My problem is that when I try to call test() it works pretty well but when I call test.delay() it returns “received unregistered task”.

*starting the service.*
[image]

*running test() and test.delay()* (as you can see, the first one works.)
[image]

*result from test.delay()*

[image]

Settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IMPORTS=("tasks")

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "systech_account",
    #...
)
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def test():
    return "Just a Test"
```

celeryconfig.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'root.settings')

app = Celery()
# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

.

---

I'm using

- django 1.9
- celery 4.0
- Redis Server 2.8.4
- Python 2.7
- Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Just restarting Celery should solve your problem. This is happening because when you call `test()`, it is just a method, so it does not need any pre-registering.

When you call `test.delay()`, though, a message (task) is sent to the broker, which is then fetched by a worker. This worker will only know tasks which were registered before Celery was started. That's why it won't detect tasks that are implemented after starting Celery.

**EDIT**

BTW, another thing I noted is that you seem to have named your file as `Tasks.py`. It *must* be `tasks.py` instead for Celery to autodiscover tasks successfully in it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When you say "restarting Celery" do you mean to re-run the *celery --app=root.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO*? If so, I already did that but no luck. As for Tasks.py, it's just a type. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using djcelery and uninstall celery since djcelery doesn't support Celery 4.0 and install the 3.1.25 instead.